# Compare a list of lists with a list

Tags: python, list

I have a (Python) list 'A' and corresponding to many (*but not all*) elements of that list I have specific numbers. For example, I have the following list A

A = [2, **4**, 6, **8**, **10**, 12]

And, the entries of the list A which are in boldface (*i.e.* **4**, **8** and **10**) have the respective values (**5**, **25**, **55**) associated with them, while the other entries of list A (*i.e.* 2, 6, 12) do not have any values associated with them.

I am able to make a list of lists in Python for the entries that have values associated with them. Like

```
ListofLists = [[4, 5], [8, 25], [10, 55]]
```

The source of the "*associated values*" (5,25,55) is **ListofLists** and it has to be compared with the list **A**. As shown in the example, I expect to find entries in list A that do not have any values attached with them (like missing values) and I want to fix that.

I want to fill **zeros as values** for the **entries in list A which do not have any associated values**, and **by comparing 'ListofLists' with 'A'**, I want to come up with a new ListofLists which should read

```
ListofLists_new = [[2, 0], [4, 5], [6, 0], [8, 25], [10, 55], [12, 0]]
```

Comment: What is the source of your "associated values"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the associated values are mapped using `dict` like:

```
associated_values = {8: 25, 10: 55, 4: 5}

# you may get this `dict` via. type-casting `ListofLists` to `dict` as:
#     associated_values = dict(ListofLists)
```

In order to create a mapped list with missing values filled with 0, you may use `dict.get(key, 0)` along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> my_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

>>> [[v, associated_values.get(v, 0)] for v in my_list]
[[2, 0], [4, 5], [6, 0], [8, 25], [10, 55], [12, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a dict, it should do your job well.

First, create a dict similar to your ListofLists, using the first element as key and second element as value for each entries.

Then using dict.get(key, default_value) will be a much more elegant solution.
In your case, dict.get(key,0) would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Turn `ListofLists` into a `dict`, and then you can use `dict.get`. Like this:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
li = [[4, 5], [8, 25], [10, 55]] 
li_dict = {k:v for k,v in li}
out = [[a,li_dict.get(a,0)] for a in A]
print(out) # [[2, 0], [4, 5], [6, 0], [8, 25], [10, 55], [12, 0]]
```

(I'm not sure if this is what you want)

Answer (score 1):

Considering association is done in a dictionary

```
assoc = {4:5,8:25,10:55}
A = [2,4,8,6,10,12]
lstoflst = []
for i in A:
    if i in assoc.keys():
        lstoflst.append([i,assoc[i]])
    else:
        lstoflst.append([i,0])
print(lstoflst)
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the suggestions to use a `dict` are right. If you can't use a dict - because this is homework or something - here's some code that does what I think you want:

```
#!python3

A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
ListofLists = [[4, 5], [8, 25], [10, 55]]

result = []

for a in A:
    for k,v in ListofLists:
        if a == k:
            result.append([k,v])
            break
    else:
        result.append([a,0])

assert result == [[2, 0], [4, 5], [6, 0], [8, 25], [10, 55], [12, 0]]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary for this:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
ListOfLists = [[4, 5], [8, 25], [10, 55]]
lol_dict = {key:value for key,value in ListOfLists}
out_dict = {key:lol_dict.get(key,0) for key in A}
final_out = [[key,value] for key,value in out_dict.iteritems()]
print final_out

[[2, 0], [4, 5], [6, 0], [8, 25], [10, 55], [12, 0]]
```